# Compare length of multiple array and display error if unequal

Tags: matlab, compare, string-length

I have multiple array of real numbers.
Eg.

```
a = [1:5]
b = [11:15]
c = [100:105]
d = [200:210]
```

I want a shorter code, if number of arrays are in 100's. What i know is,

```
if length(a) == length(b) && length(b) == length(c) && length(c)== length(d)
else
error ('Length of data series is unequal. Correct it.')
end
```

This will display an error if length if all series is not equal but how could it be done in small code when array number and size is very large (in 100's) ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
%%// Get all the arrays/vectors into a cell array, with each element in each cell
A = [{a},{b},{c},{d}]

%%// Get the number of elements of all the cells, that is number of elements
%%// of all vectors into an array. This, this array could be thought of as an
%%// array of sizes
numels = cellfun(@numel,A)

%%// Now that we have an array of sizes, we need to make sure that 
%%//all the sizes are same. So when we compare all sizes to 
%%// any randomly picked one (first one in this case), must be matching, 
%%// which is being covered by the command - all.
if ~all(numels==numels(1))
    error ('Length of data series is unequal. Correct it.')
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was about to suggest. The cell array is the most obvious data structure for generalizing to an arbitrary number of arrays. Any reason you declared `A` using `cat` rather than `A = {a,b,c,d}`?

Comment: @musicinmybrain Oh yeah you are right, don't need cat command there although it meant the samething, thanks!

Comment: @Divakar Can you explain how it works, i.e what function works in what fashion?

Comment: @musicinmybrain Please feel the musical comments embedded into the codes :)